# How to send String values from one activity to another through intent?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

How do I send values that the user puts in editText in StartActivity to textView3 in  Second Activity? I am essentially asking the user for his name in StartActivity and then printing "Your name is ___" in the SecondActivity.

I did try to use  and then in the SecondActivity  but it shows null what do I do?

StartActivity::

```
    button.setOnClickListener 
    {
        val name = editText.text.toString()
        val intent2 = Intent (this, SecondActivity::class.java)

        intent.putExtra("name", name)
        startActivity(intent2)

    }
```

SecondActivity::

```
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) 
    {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_second)

      val name2 = intent.getStringExtra("name")
      textView3.text = name2
    }
```

The error was that it prints "Your name is null".`enter code here`

Comment: change to `val intent2 = Intent (this, SecondActivity::class.java)
        intent2.putExtra("name", name)
       startActivity(intent2)`

Answer (score 7):

This looks like a typo that Kotlin is helping you make. The name of the intent you're starting is `intent2`, but you're adding the "name" string to `intent`. This is possible because Kotlin is letting you access the results of `getIntent()` (i.e. the `Intent` object used to launch the current activity) as though it were a property.

Change this line to use `intent2` and it should all start working:

```
intent2.putExtra("name", name)
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `intent.putExtra("name", name)` to `intent2.putExtra("name", name)`

**Note:** Whenever you don't have a variable `intent` in your scope. Kotlin extensions take `intent` value from `getIntent()` which is your previous intent. And that's why you have missed the compilation error.